# Is there a plugin for Sublime Text 3 which shows element's parents?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, nested, sublime-text-plugin

phpStorm has it by default:
[image]

it works for HTML tags and CSS nesting with preprocessors like LESS/SASS.

Comment: This would be awesome! I need it for things like LESS...

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called [xpath](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/xpath), which will show, in the status bar, the ancestors of the element at the cursor position for HTML and XML documents.

Disclaimer: I have contributed to the development of this plugin.

As far as I know, no similar plugin exists for CSS or pre-processed CSS files yet.